# Monitoring Tabular Refresh with REST API - Obtaining Refresh ID

Tags: rest, azure, ssas, ssas-tabular

I am refreshing tabular models in Azure using a logic app and the REST API. This is detailed here;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh

The refresh starts with the POST, which is fine. however I want to poll the SSAS instance to know when the processing is complete. The documentation states that;

"The Location header in the response includes the refresh ID. The client application can disconnect and check the status later if required because it is asynchronous."

However the header response is like this;

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "x-ms-root-activity-id": "37b7dda1-5ee8-4a56-868a-c98bfea617ec",
        "x-ms-current-utc-date": "1/28/2019 5:23:10 PM",
        "X-Frame-Options": "deny",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
        "Content-Security-Policy": "script-src 'self'",
        "Date": "Mon, 28 Jan 2019 17:23:10 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "Content-Length": "2680",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
...
```

There is no location value giving me an ID to monitor with GET requests. I know I can return all the Historical requests using a GET with no ID provided - however this is going to be clunky in a function app to establish which one was the most recent etc..

Does anyone know how I could obtain the refresh Id?

Comment: Hey, Did you find it? I am in the same situation and dont know where to find refreshid

Comment: @Kaja I didn't, are you using logic apps? I did find a work around that I can post on this.

Comment: This is such garbage. There is definitely no Location header to be found. Microsoft has dropped the ball extremely hard on documentation across the board in the last several years. It's literally trash.

Comment: Yeah, from data factory or logic apps you can't see it. What I do is get all the refreshes and loop through them checking the status. As I am refreshing a tabular only one process can be active at once so I take the guid for the refresh that is in process. I then poll that. Alternatively you could take a timestamp before you post to refresh it and loop through all the refreshes greater than thst time.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the HTTP Activity and click the ellipsis in the upper right-hand corner to bring up the menu, then click the "Settings" icon. In settings, disable the behavior for "Asynchronous Pattern", since you want to do the polling yourself.

This will cause the HTTP Activity to stop when it receives an HTTP Response Status Code of 202, and the Location Header will be available. With the "Asynchronous Pattern" enabled, it polls until it receives a 200, which only returns the representation of the resource (the Refresh). Unfortunately, the representation does not include its own identifier, which is hilarious in this particular use case.